# Alternate way of writing the Jacobi iteration method

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

The Jacobi method can be written as

$x_{\nu + 1}=D^{-1}(A_L+A_R)x_{\nu} + D^{-1}y$.

Why is it the case that the author then makes the following claim? I don't see the equivalence between these methods.

> Each step of the Jacobi iterations method can be written in the form
>
> $x_{\nu + 1}= x_{\nu} + D^{-1}(y-Ax_{\nu})$
> indicating how the new approximation $x_{\nu+1}$ is obtained by correcting the previous approximation $x_{\nu}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the other answer, any iterative method for solving $Ax=b$ of the form
$$
Mx_{k+1}=Nx_k+b
$$
induced by a splitting $A=M-N$ with a nonsingular $M$ can be rewritten as
$$
x_{k+1}=M^{-1}(Nx_k+b)=M^{-1}[(M-A)x_k+b]=x_k+M^{-1}(b-Ax_k).
$$

In case of the Jacobi method, it is enough to substitute $M=D$.

Comment: +1 for this rewrite that presents the familiar iteration in the preferred form of the current approximation plus a correction that is likely to be relatively small compared with the current approximation.

Answer (score 0):

I am totally clueless about this Jacobi method thing, but I think that the equivalence between the two methods can be seen as follows :
\begin{align}x_{\nu} + D^{-1}(y-Ax_{\nu}) &= x_{\nu} - D^{-1}Ax_{\nu} + D^{-1}y\\
&= D^{-1}Dx_\nu - D^{-1}Ax_{\nu} + D^{-1}y \\
&=D^{-1}(D - A)x_\nu + D^{-1}y\end{align}

So if you can write $D-A\equiv A_L + A_R $, then the two expressions of $x_{\nu+1} $ are indeed equivalent.